# Get Comma Separated Ids in variable plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, string-aggregation

I have a table like this

```
id  |  Name
===========
1   |  A
2   |  A
3   |  A
4   |  B
5   |  B
6   |  C
```

i am writing select id from tbl where name = "A", i want to get all three ids (1,2,3) like this separated by comma in a single variable and then I want to use that variable in another select query having IN clause, any help please?

Comment: Have you tried a query yet?  The best way to master SQL (or any language) is to practice using it.

Comment: currenty i am taking one by one id value and using for loop, but now i want to get all ids separated by comma and then want to use one select statement with IN clause, don't have any idea how to do this..:(

Comment: Read the above link.

Comment: use `listagg()`

Comment: tried using listagg(), it is giving result of string concatenation is too long.

Comment: Does a string variable with comma separated values work inside an IN? Maybe verify that first!

Comment: *" i want to get all three ids (1,2,3) like this separated by comma in a single variable and then I want to use that variable in another select query having IN clause"* Why? Why do you want to that rather having an IN clause which is just `in ( select id from tbl where name = 'A')`?

Comment: @APC anyways it is not working inside IN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, using [`listagg()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) should do the trick:

```
SELECT listagg(id, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id) as concatenation 
FROM mytable 
WHERE name = 'A'
```

Answer (score 0):

this is working:

```
create table ns_1111(col1 number,col2 varchar(20));

insert into ns_1111 values(1,'A');
insert into ns_1111 values(2,'A');
insert into ns_1111 values(3,'A');
insert into ns_1111 values(4,'B');
insert into ns_1111 values(5,'B');
insert into ns_1111 values(6,'C');
SELECT * FROM ns_1111;


select * from (SELECT LISTAGG(col1, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col1)
FROM ns_1111 group by col2) where rownum<=1   ;
```

output:

```
1, 2, 3
```

Comment: SQL Queries are ordered non-deterministicly (unless an `ORDER BY` clause is specified). Shuffle your `INSERT` statements (or enable row-movement on your table), or try to get the results for `B`, and your query will not give the expected results as you are relying on the non-deterministic order to give you deterministic results.

Comment: i ll then  use order by in col1

Comment: @MT0    i shffled the inserts then also its showing corrrect outputs you a carelessly downgrading my answer

Comment: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6d62a/1) gives an example of it not giving the expected results. If you use `ORDER BY col1` in the inner query then you will get `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`.

Comment: my sql developer gives the correct answers  is there any differenc ebetween fiddle and sql developer

Comment: @MT0 why have you given 1 1  instead of B there

Comment: check for this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/56e34/1

Comment: @MT0 you have inserted wrong inputs for B

Comment: To show you where the query goes wrong - you are not filtering on `A` you are relying on an undocumented implicit alpha-numeric ordering which one of `LISTAGG` or `GROUP BY` applies when grouping the rows and then filtering to get the row with the first alpha-numeric value. This is not what the OP wanted (although it co-incidentally gets the correct value for their data) but if you change the data your query does not behave as the OP expects.

Comment: @MT0 yes you are right i filtered it on first row the op wanted 1,2,3 in the IN cliause